# select rows by value from a data frame in a list to assign new value r

Tags: r, list, select

How can I select rows of a data frame in a list by value and assign a new value to a certain column?

When I run this code:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(10,55,32,78,47, NA),
                 y = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "d"))

df1 <- data.frame(x = c(7.3,5.65,3.72,7.81,4.79, NA),
                 y = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "d"))

dat <- list("df" = df, "df1" = df1)

dat[['df']]['y' == "d", 1] <- 15
```

the value 15 is assigned to all the values of column `x` and `y`.

I only want the column `x` at `y == "d"` to be 15 in the data frame `df`. I don't want to transform the list of 2 data frames to 2 single data frames but select the row where `y == "d"` from the data frame df within the list. How could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with `lapply` to loop through the `list`, extract the column 'x' where 'y' is "d" and assign it to 15;  Make sure to return the whole dataset afterwards

```
lapply(dat, function(v) {
         v$y <- as.character(v$y)
         v$x[v$y =="d"] <- 15
     v})
```

If the assignment needs to be only for a particular dataset

```
dat$df$x[dat$df$y=="d"] <- 15
```

Also, if the assignment needs to be done by doing a check on the `names` of the `list`, then loop through the `names` and then do the assignment

```
for(nm in names(dat)) if(nm == "df") dat[[nm]]$x[dat[[nm]]$y=='d'] <- 15
```

Comment: Actually I need to convert the column to character. Additionally the `y == d` occurs in both data frames within the list. I'll edit my post.

Comment: @yPennylane  Update the post.  You could have done this easily while constructing the data.frame using `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`. The `y == d` can occur in `n` number of datasets in the `list` and it wont' have any impact here on the code

Comment: I tested your code. The `x` at row `y == d` in the data frame `df1` also turned to 15. How can I assign 15 to `x` at row `y == d` in the data frame `df`, but not to `df1`?

Comment: @yPennylane  You meant to only do this on a particular dataset in the `list`?

Comment: yes only on a particular dataset (`df`) in the `list`

Comment: @yPennylane  Updated the post

Comment: I need to change `df` in a loop. Can I access it like that `dat$dataset[i]$x` ? `dat` und `x` doesn't change.

Comment: @yPennylane  Yes, you can do it in a loop (but not the way you mentioned)

Comment: @yPennylane  Updated with an option you mentioned

Comment: thank you very much. I thought about a loop like this: `targets <- c("df", "df1"); for (i in 1:length(targets) {lapply(dat, function(v) {
         v$y <- as.character(v$y)
         v$x[v$y =="d"] <- 15
     v})}`. But where should I put the `i`?

Comment: @yPennylane  If you are looping through the `for` loop no need for `lapply`.  With `lapply`. it would be `lapply(names(dat), function(x) if(x == 'df') ...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178085/discussion-between-ypennylane-and-akrun).

Comment: continue discussion in chat?

Answer (score 1):

You can try a tidyverse as well

```
library(tidyverse)
map(dat, ~mutate(., x = ifelse(y == "d", 15, x)))
$df
   x y
1 10 a
2 55 a
3 32 b
4 78 b
5 47 c
6 15 d

$df1
     x y
1 7.30 a
2 5.65 a
3 3.72 b
4 7.81 b
5 4.79 c
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you replace NA with 15.
dat[[1]][1][6,] <- 15